# Function overloading in Lua?

Tags: function, lua, functional-programming, variable-assignment

I am throwing together som scripts ("scenes") in the Fibaro home automation system and need to introduce myself to how to do nice things in Lua. Fibaro has it's own debug function, but for simple testing of Lua functions not having to work all the time in the Fibaro Lua scene interface would be preferable.

There is a function `fibaro:debug`which handles simple printing of information in the interface. Basically what `print` does on the console. 
So, what I would like to do in my function is assign an alias to the one of these two functions that is available at the moment.

I tried handling it like a default value:

```
local printFunc = fibaro:debug or print;
```

which does not work. An explicit IF/ELSE block also fails:

```
if(fibaro:debug == nil) then printFun = fibaro:debug;else  printFun =print;end;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: The question title is misleading. Function overloading is the option to have multiple functions with the same name that are selected by the caller by the amount (and/or) type of arguments. A related concept is default parameters, the functionality of both concepts is comparable. What you seem to ask for is shadowing, replacing (or maybe overriding) of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local printFunc = print
if (fibaro or {}).debug then 
   function printFunc(...) 
      return fibaro:debug(...)
   end
end
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The colon operator can only be used in method calls and so this is a syntax error:

```
local printFunc = fibaro:debug or print
```

This can be written using the dot operator

```
local printFunc = fibaro.debug or print
```

but if `fibaro.debug` exists, then you'll need to supply `printFunc` explicitly with a `fibaro` object that `fibaro.debug` expects as its first (hidden) argument.

Comment: Ok, this is actually nicer. Will try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
local printFunc = (fibaro or {}).debug and function(...) return fibaro:debug(...) end or print
```

Comment: Would be nice if you could elaborate a bit :)

Comment: @filmor The code is pretty self explanatory. It just uses Boolean logic to avoid having to go through an if statement. Makes it a nice and clean one-liner.

Comment: For me, a one-liner is not *nice* exactly when it causes a horizontal scrollbar in the browser.